# Как заполнить NSDictionary данными на русском языке правильно?

Tags: xcode, ios

Есть NSDictionary с названиями стран и картинками

```
NSDictionary *result = [[NSDictionary alloc]
                        initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"USA.png", @"США",
                        @"EC.png", @"ЕС",
                        @"Russia.png", @"Россия",
                        @"Brazil.png", @"Бразилия",
                        @"Argentina.png", @"Аргентина",
                        @"Australia.png", @"Австралия",
                        @"Belgium.png", @"Бельгия",
                        @"Canada.png", @"Канада",
                        @"China.png", @"Китай",
                        @"England.png", @"Англия",
                        @"Estonia.png", @"Эстония",
                        @"Finland.png", @"Финляндия",
                        @"France.png", @"Франция",
                        @"Germany.png", @"Германия",
                        @"Greece.png", @"Греция",
                        @"India.png", @"Индия",
                        @"Italy.png", @"Италия",
                        @"Japan.png", @"Япония",
                        @"Mexico.png", @"Мексика",
                        @"Netherlands.png", @"Нидерланды",
                        @"New-Zealand.png", @"Новая Зеландия",
                        @"Norway.png", @"Норвегия",
                        @"Scotland.png", @"Шотландия",
                        @"Spain.png", @"Испания",
                        @"Switzerland.png", @"Швейцария",
                        @"Portugal.png", @"Португалия",
                        @"United-Kingdom.png", @"Британия",
                        @"Turkey.png", @"Турция",
                        @"Sweden.png", @"Швеция",
                        @"Denmark.png", @"Дания",
                        @"Czech-Republic.png", @"Чехия",
                        @"Singapore.png", @"Сингапур",
                        @"Ireland.png", @"Ирландия",
                        @"Austria.png", @"Австрия",
                        @"South-Korea.png", @"Южная Корея",
                        @"Romania.png", @"Румыния",
                        @"Cyprus.png", @"Кипр",

                        nil];
```

В NSLog они выходят как в unicode. 
При получении данных с сервера мне надо найти картинку по имени, но кодировки словаря и аттрибута xml разные.

```
    NSString *countryImageString = [self.countrySet objectForKey:event.eventCountry];
    if (countryImageString.length == 0) {
        calCell.countryImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Unknown.png"];
    } else {
        calCell.countryImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:countryImageString];
    }
```

С сервера приходит например "США", но в словаре он записан как "\U0421\U0428\U0410" и соответственно ничего не выходит. Как заполнить plist в нормальной кодировке или на лету конвертировать eventCountry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
const char *temp = [event.eventCountry UTF8String];
NSString *country = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: temp];
NSString *countryImageString = [self.countrySet objectForKey: country];
```

Comment: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'const char *'

Comment: Прошу прощения, не учел, что получаете NSString. Ответ поправил.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я тоже так пробовал. Но ошибка была оказывается в том, что в eventCountry на конце стоял знак переноса /n. Я полдня уже убил на это ))) Просто отрезал его и все заработало. Вчера написал класс к AFNetworkXMLRequest  для парсинга XML и этот кусок перестал работать. До этого был TouchXML и все было нормально, видимо он сам все отрезает лишнее.